# Adjusting xargs to accept ls -lh

Tags: linux, find, size, filesize, xargs

I want to find files larger than X MB, so I run

```
find data/ -size +2M
```

but I need MB next to each file, so I tried this:

```
find data/ -size +2M | xargs -I '{}' ls -lh '{}'
```

Above seems to list all files regardless of size, is the xargs part incorrect and it also does a `ls` on the `data/` rather than on the matching files ?

**How should the above be written ?**

It worked OK if I specify `-type f` but I think that is not the solution.

```
find data/ -size +2M -type f | xargs -I '{}' ls -lh '{}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you `sudo find / -size +2M -exec ls -s1h {} \;`